# IBM Worklight - Difference between "applicationcenter" and "appcenterconsole" URLs

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

Whenever I hit the URL `http://server:9080/applicationcenter/` it is redirecting to `http://server:9080/appcenterconsole/console.html`.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `http://your-server:9080/applicationcenter/` is the previous Application Center console URL, and in newer versions of Worklight it is `http://your-server:9080/appcenterconsole/`, [as shown in the Worklight 6.1.0.x user documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/t_starting_the_application_cente.html).

So they are one and the same. It's just a re-direct for backwards compatibility's sake.

Comment: Thank u so much  for the ans Idan, but why there is two war files  namely appcenterconsole.war and applicationcenter.war in WL 6.1 ? if it is same application..!

Comment: appcenterconsole.war - The WAR file for the Application Center console user interface web application. ****** applicationcenter.war - 
The WAR file for the Application Center REST services web application.  Take some time to read the user documentation IBM provides: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_distrib_struct_wl_server.html

Comment: Great. Please mark this question as Answered when possible.